Hybridauth 3 not returning given_name and family_name
I have installed Hybridauth 3 using composer. I get fields like email, but not name, given_name and family name. Below are the codes from Provider\Google.php:
    $response = $this->apiRequest('oauth2/v3/userinfo');

    $data = new Data\Collection($response);

    if (!$data->exists('sub')) {
        throw new UnexpectedApiResponseException('Provider API returned an unexpected response.');
    }

    $userProfile = new User\Profile();

    $userProfile->identifier = $data->get('sub');
    $userProfile->firstName = $data->get('given_name');
    $userProfile->lastName = $data->get('family_name');
    $userProfile->displayName = $data->get('name');
    $userProfile->photoURL = $data->get('picture');
    $userProfile->profileURL = $data->get('profile');
    $userProfile->gender = $data->get('gender');
    $userProfile->language = $data->get('locale');
    $userProfile->email = $data->get('email');

    $userProfile->emailVerified = $data->get('email_verified') ? $userProfile->email : '';

